# How do you protect the Raspberry Pi when you are carrying it about?

Tags: hardware, case

I am getting mine this week (or so I am told) and I am nervous about breaking it on the move since it looks so open and bare.

How do you bring it around without breaking it?

---

It has arrived. The packet says:

> This product should be placed on a stable, flat, non-conductive
>   surface in use and should not be contacted by conductive items.

Translation:

> This product should be put on the table, but don't drop your change
>   on it.

Comment: A better translation would be "don't put your grubby static-charged fingers on it". *You* are a conductive surface. Ground yourself!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VHS-Pi (Credit to  Maarten) as a case - built as a portable media server (when visiting friends)

Includes:

```
-RaspPi (duh) fully un-modified with the following directly connected
--Ethernet 'break-out' cable
--Audio 'break-out' cable (not fully completed yet)
--5v Supplied over GPIO
-7-Port D-link Hub (4 ports exposed, 3 for internal use)
--Wifi dongle
--Bluetooth dongle
--USB thumbdrive for added storage (not pictured)
```

[image]

Plugged in
[image]

Inside the VHS Tape Case

[image]

source and more photos
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12925&p=136708

Comment: you win, the box wouldn't do for someone as destructive as I. I have no vhs tapes though... I can't believe it's thin enough for that.

Comment: Added photo on inside the VHS case - contains the pi and 7 port hub - would like to create my own version of this.

Comment: Dude, the only thing you are missing are some RGB leds that illuminate the box in a wicked way. That is the best mod I have seen for 2012! *Now where did I put my VHS cassettes...* PS Can we have the source for sticker please ? :-)

Comment: Please contact Maarten via the RPi forum for requests http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12925&p=136708

Answer (score 10):

I have a 3D printed case.  If you know anyone with access to a 3D printer, there are a variety of case designs freely available on [thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi&sa=Search).

[image: 3D printed case]

I'm also in the midst of a case mod project to put my Raspberry Pi inside of a Sega Genesis cartridge.  I'm also planning to use the box that the cartridge came in as an additional carrying case, as well.  However, this method involves some modifying of the cartridge and case, so don't do this if you aren't looking to use a rotary tool.

Answer (score 8):

So far I just keep it in the box it came in from Farnell. You can cut holes for whichever ports you are using.

Comment: i'm doing exactly what you recommend to my raspberry.

Answer (score 8):

I'm looking at getting a professional case ordered, but in the meantime I built one out of Lego. It works surprisingly well at being effectively a prototype case, and it allows you to easily keep spaces open for ports.

Answer (score 7):

Some type of case is the best protection from drops, spills, things falling on it, accidental contact, static electricity and dust. Having said that the price, durability, and protection provided by a case varies tremendously, as evidenced by Gnibblers low tech approach to the [Pibow](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/cases), discussed on the Raspberry Pi site earlier this week.

If you intend to move your Pi around a lot some type of case/enclosure is a worthwhile expense for the protection it provides. Browsing the [Raspberry Pi Forum's Case thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=40&sid=8180150c6b7536c7fe936315bd56eec1) should give you plenty of ideas/choices.

Comment: I really like the look of the pibow.